# Ampscript condition else/if to show the default link and conditional issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, conditional, operators

I have DE lists like this for "Fruits" category:

"Apple", "Apple A", "Apple 2", "Apple red", "Apple green", "Apple CA", "Mango", "Mango Lala", "Mango B", "Mango White", "Mango special", "Mango yes" etc

And for "Year" category:

"2023", "2024", "2025", so on

Basically, I want to show if the fruits name is listed and year is correct then it would specific link, otherwise if fruits name not within in that category and year less than 2023 then it would show default link.

My code:

```
var @lookupValue

set @lookupValue = [Fruits] 

SET @Fruits= [Fruits]
set @Year= [Year]

SET @LinkDefault = "google.com"

if IndexOf(Fruits,'Apple') > 0 or IndexOf(Fruits,'Apple red') > 0 and @Year >= 2023 then
    SET @LinkSE = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'LinkHero' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)
 
    SET @Link1 = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'Link1' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)
    
    SET @Link2 = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'Link2' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)
    
    SET @Link3 = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'Link3' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)  
   
elseif IndexOf(Fruits,'Mango') > 0 or IndexOf(Fruits,'Mango red') > 0 and @Year >= 2023 then
    SET @LinkSE = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'LinkHero' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)
 
    SET @Link1 = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'Link1' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)
    
    SET @Link2 = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'Link2' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)
    
    SET @Link3 = lookup('FruitsJourney_Links', 'Link3' ,'Fruits', @lookupValue)  

else @Fruits != [Fruits ] and @Year <= 2022 then
    SET @LinkSE = @LinkDefault 
 
    SET @Link1 = @LinkDefault 
    
    SET @Link2 = @LinkDefault 
    
    SET @Link3 = @LinkDefault    

endif
```

I think my condition is correct, however,the default link doesn't work, can anyone check what is the issue with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: The `@lookupvalue` and `@ModelYear` variables have not been set, at least not in the piece of code you provided

Comment: @zuzannamj I just made an edit, adding the lookupvalue and year

Comment: Are the years listed in an Array? In your sample code above, it reads: "2023", "2024", "2025" and so on Is it stored as an Array or a String? Either one won't work given the condition if it's looking for >= conditional. @Year >= 2023 Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's not an array, I just add the year to show sample. My conditon is also like that, but still does't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if the last "else" statement was changed to "elseif" the default links would show.

```
elseif @Fruits != [Fruits ] and @Year <= 2022 then
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I'm not sure what's the issue,,

Answer (score 0):

An ELSE statement does not receive any evaluation criteria.

If your goal is to evaluate several conditions using tiered logic, then if none are met assign default values, your last evaluation line is just "ELSE":

ELSE
SET @LinkSE = @LinkDefault

```
SET @Link1 = @LinkDefault 

SET @Link2 = @LinkDefault 

SET @Link3 = @LinkDefault
```

ENDIF